# open url in new tab or reuse existing one whenever possible

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

Now I have a link

```
<a href="blabla" target="_blank">link</a>
```

However, this always open up a new tab. I want the following effect

1. If the user already has a tab with the same URL, reuse that tab, and refresh if possible
2. Otherwise, open a new tab

How can I achieve this using JavaScript?

It's OK if there're only some browser-specific methods, so users of browsers without corresponding support will "fallback" to the always-new-tab way.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet for a comment, so please don't choose this as an answer, but I believe you will find a near-duplicate of this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641812/how-to-detect-that-the-same-page-is-already-opened-in-another-window-in-ie Good luck!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can set specific window's name, in order to open reuse the tab. The problem is, as far as the href will be the same, it won't be reloaded. So you can't obtain the `refresh` part easily.

So, for instance, you can have:

```
<a href="blabla" target="blabla">link</a>
<a href="foo" target="bar">link</a>
```

In JS, you can actually obtain the same, using `window.open`. You could also use the url as `target`, so that you don't need to specify manually:

```
<a href="blabla" onclick="window.open(this.href, this.href); return false">link</a>
<a href="foo" onclick="window.open(this.href, this.href); return false">link</a>
```

You could also generalize, and add a click listener to the document, in order to open some links in this way. Something like:

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="blabla">link</a>
    <a href="foo">link</a>
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("container").onclick = function(evt){
        if (evt.target.tagName === "A")
            window.open(evt.target.href, evt.target.href);

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

If the page are on the same domain, at this point you could probably trying to do an empiric refresh of the page as well.

Comment: Somehow it is not working for me. If I understood the question and answer, there suppose to be, first link click will open the new tab in browser and after any link clicked, same browser tab should be reused... I tried this solution but never worked. It opens new tab every time. Except If trigger same link, it it not opening another tab.

Comment: Note that after second Ctrl+Click browser (at least Chrome) will switch to this tab. That's not really what I would expect.

Comment: Can someone who understands this answer edit this answer into better english.

Comment: In my testing, this only works for same domain; all others open in new browser window.

Comment: I found a couple reasons why this might not be working for some URLs/domains (see comments above from @Liladhar and @llessurt).  I wrote them up as an answer on this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78202660/3791490

Answer (score 0):

setting up `target="child"` would refresh the current tab if already opened

```
<a href="https://abcd.com" target="child">ABcd</a>
<a href="https://defg.com" target="child">Defg</a>
```

Comment: I cannot make this work cross domain as in the example.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "_child" with a leading underscore? This seems to work (without the underscore, it doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

It's been 11 years since this was asked, but the problem is persistent. Standard solutions like named targets do not work as browsers abandoned support. So we built the [Reuse Tabs browser extension](https://appfluence.com/reuse-tabs-a-browser-extension/) to address this exact problem. Free and simple, no accounts required, and no tracking.