# Load _blank link in the same window if clicked twice

Tags: html

Is it possible?

So I have a link:

`<a href='/page.htm' target='_blank'>`

If they click it twice, it will load up two blank tabs.  Is there anyway to get this particular link to load in the same new tab each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign an `onclick` handler to the anchor that calls the `open` method of the window object. The first time the anchor is clicked, it opens a new browsing tab.

Notice the second parameter to the `open` method (i.e., "other-window"). This is a handle to the new tab. If you want to load new content into that tab (instead of opening yet another tab), just call the `open` method again with that same handle as the second parameter:

```
(function () {

    var childWindowOpen = false;

    window.onload = function (event) {
        var anchor = document.getElementById("child-window-link");

        anchor.onclick = function (event) {
            var childWindow;

            if (!childWindowOpen) {
                childWindow = window.open("otherpage.html", "other-window");
            } else {
                childWindow = window.open("yetanotherpage.html", "other-window");
            }
            childWindowOpen = true;
            return false;
        }
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use window.open to reuse window if opened, you can see this answer for further details:

[open url in new tab or reuse existing one whenever possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779508/open-url-in-new-tab-or-reuse-existing-one-whenever-possible)