# Reload tab content in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

how can I reload specific browser tab content? I search for solution which can not be only in JQuery (I prefer it if there more solution).

I need this:
I have page with a lot of links on another's pages (format of links: http://domain_name.cz/?still_same_text=1_1_1_1_1_1386662409 ; another page has this link: http://domain_name.cz/?still_same_text=1_1_14_1_2_1387231396 etc. everyone links has same format only to 1st number). When I click first time on some link then I load new tab (for this text I say him simply "tab2") if I click again on another link then I reload this "tab2" (= I change url in this "tab2" from current to new => I load new conent in this tab).
Is there some way to do that?

I try solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779508/open-url-in-new-tab-or-reuse-existing-one-whenever-possible) topic but this not work for me and, I mean, I have difficult problem. And I look at solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160362/load-blank-link-in-the-same-window-if-clicked-twice?lq=1) topic, but this is another problem. There is 1 link but I can have more links and there are links in JS but I need generate them in PHP.

Comment: I thought reloading tab content is a job by browser plugin - such as Chrome extension coding, and didn't know it's possible via naming target name. Good luck.

Comment: You can not take control of the clients tabs via. javascript in your webapp. As mentioned by Ken OKABE, a browser level extentsion might be the only way forward.

Comment: Thanks for comments and these informations.

Comment: Do you mind using server to accomplish this?

Comment: I mean this is not problem. But when I seen solution then I can check if this solution is way or not (I don´t know what can/can´t I do with server thing).

Answer (score 0):

I've not done this before, but the question seems interesting. Therefore, if the answers you mentioned did not work then I would try the following concept, it may not be the best, but it's something.

1- Make a tracker on the server (properly in session) to keep track of the pages that the user has opened. So whenever the user open a page, make an ajax request sending the page url with a random generated id number to be stored and checked later. **Each tab will get a different id.**

2- Add a javascript listener in all pages that keep waiting for commands from the server. Depending on the server response, those listen will do the following:

- Nothing -> in case the page is opened first time.
- [Close tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window) -> in case a new tab with same link is opened. So keep the new tab and close the old one. // Or close new one and refresh old one?
- [Update](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) -> update server once tab is opened (directly when the page gets loaded) and just [before they get closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272561/ajax-and-user-leaving-a-page), send the page url and current tab id to be check on the server.
- Keep checking server, if a newer tab with same url is opened, then close current.

I'm not sure if this solution is suitable for you, so I will only write a pseudo code. If it's applicable, then later maybe can improve it a bit.

pseudo code php: tabControl.php

```
//session array structure 
//when a new tab is added, it will take the following index of current url array. So later we can know which one is 
//$_SESSION["tracker"][ current url  ][ tab id]  newer id will be added to the array in an ascending order, not based on their value, so later we can check which tabId came later. 

$action = $_POST["action"];
$tabId = $_POST["id"];
$tabUrl = $_POST["url"];

if($action === "check")
 { 
    processTab(tabUrl , $tabId);  
 }   
elseif($action === "closing")
 {
    closeTab(tabUrl , $tabId) ; 
 }   

 /*if this a second tab opened with the same url, then echo the previous tab id and command the client to close self. 
  *if this the first tab, then store it in session. 
*/

function  processTab($tabUrl , $tabId)
{
   //if new, then pass it to addTab
  // else, check if there is a newer tab opened, then call closeTab
}

function addTab($tabUrl , $tabId)
{
   // add a new tab associated with tabUrl -> couter -> tabId
}

function  closeTab($tabUrl , $tabId)
{
   //set that $tabUrl with the id to null. 
   //and ask the client to close the tab.  //echo json_encode(array("responce"=>"closeSelf"))
}
```

And from the client side, you can use something similar to this pseudo code:

```
//current tab id
var tabId = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1); 


    //On exit, just run once before user close the tab/window. 
    $(window).unload(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'tabControl.php',
            async:false,
            data: {"url":window.location.pathname , "action":"closing" , "id":tabId}
        });
    });

// keep checking  periodically 
    function checkTabs()
    {
        //On load, just run once
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'tabControl.php',
                data: {"url":window.location.pathname , "action":"check", "id":tabId},
                type:"json",
                success:function(data)  
                        {
                          if(data.responce === "closeSelf")
                               {// if the user detected that there is a newer with this url opened. 
                                  window.close();
                               }
                        }
            }).always(function(){ setTimeout(checkTabs, 1000);});

    }

checkTabs();// to call for the first time.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this isn't a difficult problem if you use appropriate technology. Controlling specific browser tabs can be done with the browser SDK, which has access to the tab management. JavaScript or PHP themselves *cannot* access a specific tab because it would be a security breach.

**Example for Google Chrome:**

Take a look at the [chrome.tabs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) reference. There is many things you can do with tabs including what you are trying to do. For example, a user-friendly way of displaying a link that can control browser tabs would be to use a [browser popup](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#popups) (attention, this isn't the same thing as a conventional popup, a browser popup is an "internal" browser-level popup that is suggesting that this specific area may control *any part* of the browser instead of *the current page only*) that contains the links. In that popup, you could have something like this:

Browser popup (HTML):

```
<a id="myLink" href="http://wwww.google.com">This link will control a new tab</a>
```

Browser popup (JavaScript):

```
var tabNumber;
var tabCreated = false;

document.getElementById("myLink").addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (!tabCreated) {
        // create a new tab
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: this.href
        }, function(tab) {
            tabNumber = tab.id; // return ID of created tab
            tabCreated = true;
        });
    } else {
        // reload the created tab
        chrome.tabs.reload(tabNumber, null);
    }
}, false);
```

The biggest problem of your specification is that this kind of mechanism must be implemented for each browser separately and requires a plugin installation. If the link is the only browser-level access, you should consider changing its behavior so he can be part of the current page behavior.

Hope this helps! :-)