# on Select change open tab to new url. But what if the tab is closed on the next select change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I check if the user closed the the browser tab that I opened and sent to a url?

Below is my code. When the user changes the value of a select dropdown it checks to see if the browser window was opened and if so reload the url if not open a tab to the selected url.

BUT if the user changes the select value and a new tab is opened then they close it on the next select change a new tab WILL NOT OPEN.

```
urlmenu.onchange = function() {
   if (typeof(ref) != 'undefined') {
     ref.location = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value;
   } else {
     ref = window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, '_blank');
   }
};
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: why not target a tab that way if it exists it will change if not it will open

Comment: [this may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779508/open-url-in-new-tab-or-reuse-existing-one-whenever-possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a name to your window:

```
urlmenu.onchange = function() {
    window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, 'urlmenutab');
};
```

If no window with this name, the browser while create a new one. If already exists, the browser re-use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this should do the trick

```
urlmenu.onchange = function() {

    var ref = window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, 'somename', '');

};
```

Instead of using '_blank' specify a name of the tab so that it will just refresh that same tab if it's open already and not create a new one.

Using '_blank' you issues a browser command to open another tab (or window if you spesicified hiehgt)
check my example below

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
var windowOpen = null;
function myFunction() {

    windowOpen  = window.open("http://stackoverflow.com", "somename", "");

}
</script>
```