# How to stop a custom bookmarklet from opening multiple browser tabs

Tags: javascript, browser, window.location

I use a standard bookmarklet that looks something like this:

```
javascript:(function () {var p = document.title;var uri=document.location;window.location = 'http://localhost:8084/'})()
```

However, every time I use it, it generates a new tab. How do I stop `window.location` from opening a new tab, or better, how do I get it to load the page in another tab if it exists (ie, if localhost is already open, that's the tab that will be used.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question looks similar to

[open url in new tab or reuse existing one whenever possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779508/open-url-in-new-tab-or-reuse-existing-one-whenever-possible)

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

> **URL** : Optional. Specifies the URL of the page to open. If no URL is
>   specified, a new window with about:blank is opened
>
> **name** :    Optional. Specifies the target attribute or the name of the
>   window. The following values are supported:

- _blank  - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default
- _parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
- _self   - URL replaces the current page
- _top    - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded
- **name**    - The name of the window (Note: the name does not specify the
  title of the new window)

```js
     < script >
      document.getElementById("container").onclick = function(evt) {
        if (evt.target.tagName === "A")
          window.open(evt.target.href, evt.target.href);

        return false;
      } < /script>
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a href="https://www.google.com">goo</a>
  <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">sta</a>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you get a reference to the window name of a page that was not loaded programmatically? I.e., if my web app is at www.abc.com, but i am looking at www.def.com, how do I get my bookmarklet to open in www.abc.com's tab?

Comment: 1:Can you express more what are you trying to create with the help of [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or [plnkr](http://www.plnkr.co) with html + javascript + scenario explanation 2:You have created self firing function that will fire on page load ,so are you sure you don't want on click3:Please go throught [Window.name what it means](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_name.asp) And [Get_window_name_specified](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/Browser/Window/Get_window_name_specified_when_new_windows_are_created_using_the_Window_open_method_in_JavaScript.htm)