# Open a link in a new tab(in same window) or reload and focus it if it is already opened using 'href'

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I want to open a link using 'href' (not using javascript/jQuery), in a new tab in the same window. If the link is already opened it should just reload it and focus it.

How can i code to achieve this?

I tried.

```
<a href="name.html" target="_blank">Click</a>
```

It doesn't reload the page if it already exists. It opens the link in new tab again and again.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [open url in new tab or reuse existing one whenever possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779508/open-url-in-new-tab-or-reuse-existing-one-whenever-possible)

Comment: not really a duplicate, as this question is about how to do it without scripting.

Comment: @haxtbh i'm asking that without using javascript. Is that possible?

Comment: The first part of the answer in that duplicate gives the solution without JS.

Comment: @haxtbh oh. ok will see that.

Comment: @haxtbh But it doesn't focus that particular reloaded tab. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Simply give your target a unique value, like this:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="mynewwindow">Always opens in the same window</a>
```

This is the default behaviour of the target attribute. `_blank` is one of an handful special keywords, with special behaviours, as described in the [HTML standard](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#valid-browsing-context-name-or-keyword).

Note that the standard doesn't talk about windows, but about *browsing context*. A browsing context is typically a window or a tab, but this is up the browser.

As for the special keywords:

- `_blank` means *always* use a new browsing context (e.g. tab or window)
- `_self` means  *always* use the same browsing context
- `_parent` means use a parent context, if any
- `_top` means use the topmost context, if there are any parents

With iframes, things are a little bit more complex.

edit: Note also that the second time a user clicks the link, the target page will not be reloaded. If you need a refresh, you will have to use Javascript.

Comment: i'm having `<a href="page.html" target="name">click</a>` and another link with a query string as `<a href="page.html?showthis=a" target="name">clickkkk</a>`. Is that possible to relaod that `page.html` with both query string?

Comment: I don't know. Why don't you try?

Comment: it's working as per my wish but what if i don't want to refresh that new opened window ? please help me with this. I have opened new window once then it should not get refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always keep a popup "focused" you can use a trick originally found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776480/3254405). By rapidly open/close/open it we ensure it's always behaves like new window and grabs focus.

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" onclick="
if(window.open('','reuse_win') != null) {
   window.open('','reuse_win').close();
}" target="reuse_win">Always opens in the same window and FOCUS</a>
```

Also works when submitting a "form" to a targeted window.

```
<form name=f1 method=post action=test.html>

  <input type=text name=name value='123'>

  <input type='submit' value='Submit' 

  onclick="if(window.open('','reuse_win') != null) {
       window.open('','reuse_win').close();
    }; this.form.target='reuse_win'; return true;">

</form>
```