# why is href link with target="tabname" not working

Tags: html

This was working the first time I tried it, would re-use the same tab as target if it exists and create if it does not

```
<a href="www.example.com/help/section3" target="helpTab" class="helpButton">Help</a>
```

Later when I tried the link I noticed it was creating new tabs over and over if i clicked it multiple times, and not re-useing that tab it already made.

so I tried using the java window.open:

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://example.com/help/#section1', 'helpTab'); return false" class="helpButton">Help</a>
```

and still it keeps opening in new tabs over and over again.

what would cause it to stop working or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779508/open-url-in-new-tab-or-reuse-existing-one-whenever-possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open url in new tab or reuse existing one whenever possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779508/open-url-in-new-tab-or-reuse-existing-one-whenever-possible)

Comment: I can not reproduce the (strange) effect you are experiencing. The only way a new tab would be open on every visit to that link is that `target =_blank` (which is a reserved target aimed to do that behaviour). Might some scriptlet in your page have changed the value of the `target` attribute? Have you seen the _real_ target value through a developper's HTML monitor in your browser?

Comment: I get the same result when href is a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently and found two possible reasons that `target="helpTab"` might have stopped working:

1. If the target URL (`www.example.com/help/section3`) redirects to another URL, this will prevent the tab from being reused.
2. If you have a mismatch in the `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy` HTTP header between the original page and the target page, it can prevent the tab from being reused.

In my case, I had only set `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin` on the target page.  The solution was to also set the same header on the original page.